# A specialized interface of Drupal Answers for smart phones

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any policy of Stack Exchange to design and develop smart phone application specially for iPhone/Android to give interface to Stack sites or is there any application around?

If there is no such app then do people look for such thing? As I do for my android smart phone.

The application should help the complete interaction interface for active users and moderators. Definitely this type of application would not help a lot for seekers.

Comment: You know about http://stackapps.com/questions/1843/android-app-for-stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

The whole of SE has recently been tweaked to have a mobile optimized interface. It works quite well.

Comment: I am not looking to view it on mobile browsers. There should be an app to target an SE site and then filter questions of my interests with respect to tag, answer them, view and manage other basic tasks. App should be bandwidth saver on slow or costly internet services.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by Berdir in his comment, applications that allows to browse the content of SE sites in Android exists, and there are native applications for smart phones running over Operating Systems too.

I am not aware of any limitation about the usage of the Stack Exchange API made from those applications, or any specific policy in act. You should check on [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/) about that.